# Should a woman rush towards Allah and become a good housewife or follow passion in her career?

Tags: fiqh, women, work

How women should be in Islam. Can they try hard to make a successful career?

Comment: Pursuing a career should not prevent you from marrying, having children and taking care of them.

Answer (score 2):

The way you phrased the question makes it sound as if becoming a housewife is the best way to serve Allah. Which is misleading.

There is nothing in Islam preventing women from pursuing a successful passionate career. Provided the job is licit, obviously.

And just as men can be good at their job and good husbands, women can be good at their job and be good wives.

I bring to your attention that Khadidja was a successful merchant and did not stop being a successful merchant after marrying the prophet of Islam.

Also, the two women that met moses were shepherds, and Quran did not say anything about it

> When he [Moses] arrived at the well of Midian, he found there a throng of people watering [their flocks], and he found, besides them,
>   two women holding back [their flock]. He said, ‘What is your
>   business?’ They said, ‘We do not water [our flock] until the shepherds
>   have driven out [their flocks], and our father is an aged man.
>   (28:23)

In Islam, if it is not expressly forbidden, then it is considered allowed.

Comment: A woman needs her wali's consent to take up a job.

Comment: @G.Bach Present sources

Comment: Last three paragraphs [here](https://islamqa.info/en/22397), for example. As far as I can tell, there's consensus on this.

Comment: @G.Bach Both husband and wife have rights over each other. And the husband is responsible for the maintenance of the wife, so the husband is given a little more power over the wife.
However, there is no directive that it is absolutely binding if the husband prevents it. Here the duty is to solve the problem by discussing it among ourselves. These are matters of marital life, Islam has not imposed frim obligations here.

Answer (score 1):

I respect your answer but I have come across some books stating that Khadijatul-kubra raziallahu anhu was a successful woman before marriage and after marriage she dedicated herself to become a good housewife . Kindly please check the below link. 
https://www.al-islam.org/khadijatul-kubra-sayyid-ali-asghar-razwy/chapter-4-marriage.

Comment: I bring to your attention that Khadidja was a successful merchant and did not stop being a successful merchant after marrying the prophet of Islam.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my bad english (i am from indonesia)

Allah was give the best job for women to be a housewife,

if a factory can produce good product, there must be a good CEO, a good Manager, and any other employee...

our house is a factory that produce human. from a good house can make a good CEO, a good Manager, a good employee, and any other job include being a schoolar, a president, and so many other.

islam dont force u to choose either being a housewife or your career. we can choose both of them but we must prioritize ur family before anything,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QsGtXntWQww